# How to install SSL certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store?

Tags: ssl, certificate, java

Apologies in advance, I do not have an IT background and have never done this before, yet I am being asked to figure this out and to do so as soon as possible.  Our organization is trying to update its SSL certificate for a domain.  A consultant set this up for us 1 year ago and that certificate has expired.  We haven't been able to track down the consultant yet for help.  We have a Windows 2008 R2 server and JBoss as a web application server.  We have certificates through InCommon SSL.  We used the first 4 common keytool commands shown [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html) to create the keystore and import the certificates to the keystore.  After some earlier mistakes, we are now pointing JBoss to the right keystore.  We have restarted everything, but are still getting the expired certificate warning when we go to one of our websites.  As someone trying to do this for the first time, what do we have to do to make websites actually use and trust the new certificates?  I try to import the certificates into browsers on my local machine and on the server and I receive a message saying the import was successful, but the certificates never show up and we still get the expired certificate warning.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found this [post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/how-to-go-about-an-ssl-certificate-renewal?rq=1) helpful to better understand what I've already done, but am still stuck on what seems to me might be the final step.

Comment: There are too many possibilities to diagnose without more information. To start with, go to the keystore Jboss is using (or at least the one you think it is using) and run `keytool -list -keystore *filename*` (I assume you have keytool in your PATH since you say you used the commands linked to; if not, use the full pathname of the keytool program.) If you have more than one PrivateKeyEntry, that's likely your problem right there; give details. If you have one PrivateKeyEntry and any number including zero of trustedCertEntry, take the alias at the left of the PrivateKeyEntry line, ...

Comment: ... and do the same command with `-v -alias *alias*` addedm to display the full cert info (although in a rather confusing format). Look only at the part after `Certificate[1]` and before `Certificate[2]`. It should start with `Owner:` with CN= your server's domain name. Check the `Valid from ... until` dates and see if they match what you expect. If not, post details. If so, connect with a browser than can override the warning (IE and Firefox can, I don't know about others) and display the cert info *as seen by the browser*. ...

Comment: ... In the browsers I've seen, click on the padlock and follow buttons that say anything like "certificate details". If not, identify your browser. You should eventually get a display with fields like Subject (or Owner or Issued to), Issuer (or Issued by), Serial(Number), Validity, and so on. Compare at least Subject, Issuer, and Validity start and end to the values you got with keytool; if different, post details. If the browser shows the correct and unexpired cert for your server, it is remotely possible the CA cert or "chain" is bad, but good CAs don't do that.

Comment: Thank you, @dave_thompson_085!  You were right that having MULTIPLE PrivateKey entries was the problem.  We had mistakenly added another one the other day and did not realize it was still there after we updated the other certificates.  We deleted the one that did not belong with the "keytool -delete -alias *mydomain* -keystore keystore.jks" command, restarted JBoss, and we are in business!   Thanks again!  Please feel free to post an Answer and I will mark the question as answered so you get the credit.